# Oracle pl/sql query add spaces to number so that it right aligns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a query which returns a  price  which is a number(16,2) data type.

So  the query SELECT  PRICE FROM PRODUCT ;

it should return

```
   10.00
 1234.00     --> values are right aligned; space needs to be added to 10.00 
                 to align it with 1234.00
```

How many spaces to align is dynamic we know the datatype length is (14,2)  , so  I want to convert the number to char and add spaces to left of the number.

```
  SELECT LPAD(p.price , (17 - LENGTH(TO_CHAR(p.price))),' ')  FROM Product.
```

I tried the above query but it is not giving me the right result.

I just wanted to know what is wrong with it

Comment: I suggest using your display application to align the data.

Answer (score 5):

`LPAD` takes the *ultimate* length of the expression as the second argument, not the number of characters to *add*:

```
SELECT LPAD(TO_CHAR(p.price,'99999990D99'),17) FROM Product p
```

Comment: AS soon as I do LPAD(To_char) or just LPAD() I am loosing my 00 precision value so number which is suppose to display 100.00 is getting displayed as 100 , how can I retain that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT LPAD(TO_CHAR(p.price,'99999990D009'),17) FROM Product p

Comment: Could you develop a bit more your answer ?